# TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) <python> <OpenCV> <tesseract>

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to do a text recognition on invoices.

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('bill_copy.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'], d['top'], d['width'], d['height'])
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow(img, 'img')
```

When i run it, i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntmYX.png)

Comment: I don't know exactly how pytesseract works, but I reckon it returns a tuple of coords for the boxes, you're looping over n_boxes, but nowhere you use the index, i. I imagine you're passing the tuple of box-coordinates, instead of one of the coordinates. Try printing the value of x, to see if my suspicion is correct.

Comment: @Leander, i get this

[0, 548, 548, 548, 548, 1146, 624, 624, 624, 624, 932, 1209, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2047, 2047, 2047, 2047]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/BashundharaIT/Bill OCR Python OpenCV/align_documents.py", line 13, in <module>
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Comment: i apologize for so many edits, my network is struggling.

Comment: Exactly, you're being passed the coordinates of multiple boxes, check Peters answer down below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is in the following statement:

```py
(x, y, w, h) = (d['left'], d['top'], d['width'], d['height'])
```

You need to get ith value of each region

```py
(x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
```

The problem should be solved

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of x, y, w, h is an array of every divided character, But in the loop it draws the rectangle one by one.

So you need to send an integer for those parameter(x, y, w, h) every loop.

And there is plenty of error in your code. The right code should be like that:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('bill_copy.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
(x, y, w, h) = (d['left'], d['top'], d['width'], d['height'])

for i in range(n_boxes):
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x[i], y[i]), (x[i] + w[i], y[i] + h[i]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand my mistakes now

Comment: You welcome, remember to use cv2.waitkey(0) to display your image successfully.